# Häufige Fragen nach Bestätigung: Sind die dialektbedingt?

Tags: dialect, rhetoric

Mir ist nach einem Umzug aufgefallen, dass viele Personen in der neuen Umgebung häufig – auch innerhalb von Sätzen – rhetorische Fragen nach Bestätigung stellen.

Ein Beispiel könnte so aussehen:

> Ich gehe gern in‘s Kino, ja?, und finde die aktuellen Popcorn-Preise, ja?, viel zu hoch.

Nachdem ich kürzlich schon herausgefunden habe, dass die (nach meinem Gefühl dümmlich wirkende) Ersetzung von „ch“-Lauten durch „sch“-Laute (zum Beispiel wird „Eiche“ „Eische“ ausgesprochen) dialektbedingt zu sein scheint, frage ich mich, ob das für diese rhetorischen Zwischenfragen nach Verständnis (die dem gegenüber die Fähigkeit absprechen, einfache Zusammenhänge zu verstehen und damit in‘s Bild passen) auch dialektbedingt sind oder was sie sonst motiviert.

Comment: Das "ja?" ist eher eine Rückbestätigung, dass die andere Person einem folgt, keine Frage nach Bestätigung der Aussage.

Comment: Richtig. Aber in der Frequenz ist mir das unbekannt. Im Schnitt alle 10 Worte, etwa - das wirkt auf mich zumindest ungewöhnlich, zumal keine Reaktion abgewartet wird, daher „rhetorisch“

Comment: Ich halte das für eine rein persönliche Angewohnheit, die nicht unbedingt mit dem Dialekt zu erklären ist. Obwohl je nach Dialekt auch andere Füllwörter genommen werden, wie zum Beispiel "woll" statt ja oder "gell" im Schwäbischen.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so. Ich kenne auch ein paar Menschen, die jeden Teilsatz mit einem "ja" schmücken müssen. Das ist bei manchen Menschen Unsicherheit, andere füllen damit einfach ihre Atempausen, damit man ihnen nicht ins Wort fallen kann...

Comment: Eine super Idee einen Dialekt zu diskutieren, ohne zu sagen welchen, ja?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprachliche Füllwörter wie das **`ja`** mit fragendem Tonfall sind - wie bereits von Anderen kommentiert - als Form einer Betonung der Aussage gegenüber dem Gesprächspartner zu sehen. Wie du schon festgestellt hast geht die sprechende Person meistens davon aus, dass keine Widerrede erfolgt.

Die Füllwörter finden sich in der Umgangssprache häufiger und sind somit auch vom Bildungsgrad und den persönlichen Angewohnheiten abhängig.

Gleichwohl sehe ich hier die überwiegend dialektbedingte Verwendung.

Ein wenig persönliches in Zusammenhang mit deiner Frage: Ich selbst lebe in den letzten 50 Jahren im fast dialektfreien Sprachraum bei Hannover. Vorher habe ich 15 Jahre in Wuppertal gewohnt. Nach dem Umzug hatte ich mit 16 in der Schule den Spitznamen **`..., woll?`**. Ich denke man kann speziell dieses Füllwort, geographisch wirklich sehr eng gefasst, auf die Umgebung der Stadt Wuppertal beschränken.

Auch für dein **`..., ja?`** und beim **`sch`** für **`ch`** kann man von dialektbedingt sprechen. Ich denke, du bist in die Gegend von Wuppertal, Oberhausen, Düsseldorf, Köln, Bonn umgezogen!?